# How to show components definer in list angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular9

I have a custom button component which has a parameter list. List contains other angular components, e.g `<mat-checkbox>` and `<button>`.

Is there any way to display all the added components to the user when she presses the button?

So far I have just a component but I have no idea how to render all component elements from that list.

```
<show-button title="Show components" components=["<mat-checkbox", "<button>"]></show-button></div>
```

Comment: I can try. Basically, I need to have a button which will need to show some predefined components. User presses the button and those predefined components will be shown to the user. 
Something like this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_toggle_hide_show, but that "This is my DIV element." will be predefined components.

Comment: They are hard coded into array. When someone is adding show-button component, she will add components to the list that she wants to show to the user. 
For example, one time list contains 2 components, like ```[<mat-checkbox>, <button>]```, next time there will be only one, like ```[<mat-checkbox]```

Comment: Can there be more than two elements other than mat-checkbox and button ? If there can be only two at most, I can provide a solution with *ngIf.

Comment: There can be more, but any solution would  be nice, even if it is *ngIf !

Comment: Please check the solution and let me know if it is sufficient for your case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217126/discussion-between-pawan-sharma-and-averagejoe9000).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by just using the *ngIf directive if I'm understanding your problem correctly.

Have a flag variable in your component and when someone clicks your button you can toggle the components showing.

Example:

Your component .ts file:

```
showContent = false;
```

And in your template:

```
<show-button (click)="showContent = !showContent">Show Components</show-button>
<ng-container *ngIf="showContent">
  <mat-checkbox></mat-checkbox>
  ....
</ng-container>
```

Comment: This is nice, but the main issue is how to show components that are in the list. 
For example, one time list contains 2 components, like ``[<mat-checkbox>, <button>]``, next time there will be only one, like ``[<mat-checkbox]``?

Comment: @AverageJoe9000, I think in your case you'll want to use <ng-content> in your show-button component. That way you can always put in what ever components you want and you can still use the ng-container with a flag variable whether to show or not to show whatever is in the ng-content

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have an input property in your `show-button` component like -

```
@Input() components: Array<>;
```

Add an object for toggling which components exist in the array:

```
injectedComponents = { 
    hasMatCheckBox: false,
    hasButton: false
}
```

Then toggle the properties based on which components are present in your array like :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.injectedComponents.hasMatCheckBox = this.components.includes("mat-checkbox");
    this.injectedComponents.hasButton = this.components.includes("button");
}
```

Then in your html file, check for individual properties :

```
<button *ngIf="injectedComponents.hasButton"></button>
<mat-checkbox *ngIf="injectedComponents.hasMatCheckBox"></mat-checkbox>
```

This should work for 2 components, though a better solution would be provide the html yourself in the component where you are including the `show-button` component by using content projection e.g.

2nd METHOD:

Parent Component -

```
<show-button title="Show components">
    <button></button>
    <mat-checkbox></mat-checkbox>
</show-button>
```

Show Button Component -

```
<div>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
<div>
```